# How to append a query string to url in codeception

Tags: codeception

I am attempting to do acceptance testing on a website using Codeception and BrowserStack. The website I am testing requires a query string appended to the url in order to sign-in.

For example: https://examplesite.com/?realm=ab-cd

I have attempted to use this url in the acceptance.suites.yml file:

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester 

modules:
    enabled:
        - WebDriver:
            url: http://examplesite.com/?realm=ab-cd
            host: 'hostmaster@examplesite.com:mykey@hub.browserstack.com'
            port: 80
            browser: firefox
            capabilities:
                javascriptEnabled: true
```

I have also attempted to place a sendGET in the actual test:

`$I->sendGET('/?realm=ab-cd');`

Both attempts result in not being able to sign in. What would the correct way to do this be?

Answer (score 1):

So I found that in the acceptance.suite.yml file, the Url that you provide can not have a query string appended to it. Following Naktibalda's suggestion, I tried a few variations to the:

```
 $I->amOnPage()
```

I found when appending a query string I had to start it with the ? (leaving off the preceding /). For example:

```
$I->amOnPage('?realm=bu-pd'); //Works
$I->amOnPage('/?realm=bu-pd'); //Doesn't work
```

Answer (score 1):

I reached this question, found a solution myself so giving it here:

`$I->amOnPage(['/path','query_param1' => 'bu-pd']);`

Answer (score 0):

`sendGET` belongs to REST module, use `amOnPage` in WebDriver test.